How to copy formula cells that contain certain text to another worksheet as values
I am trying to copy cells that contain a certain criteria to a new worksheet.
For example, in my worksheet "LOCATIONS", a CONCATENATE formula cell contains a string that would be used in an SQL script to be able to bulk create them.

I need to take the blue pieces of code in cells C8, E8, G8... (which all contain "dbo.Location", which I'm using in my InStr()) and paste them in a column as values on worksheet "SQL" but this will then expand to be quite a lot of locations and we don't want to manually copy them and rearrange them.
I found the following VBA code:
Sub Test()
Dim Cell As Range

With Sheets("LOCATIONS") 'Sheet with data to check for value
    ' loop column A untill last cell with value (not entire column)
    For Each Cell In .Range("A1:R13" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        pos = InStr(Cell.Value, "Location")
        If pos > 0 Then
            NextFreeRow = Sheets("SQL").Cells(Sheets("SQL").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
             'get the next empty row to paste data to
            .Range("I" & Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("SQL").Range("A" & NextFreeRow)
        End If
    Next Cell
End With
End Sub

Which creates this in worksheet "SQL"



Column A




#REF!


#REF!


#REF!


#REF!


"INSERT INTO dbo.Locations VALUES ('', '', '', '', , , SYSDATETIME(), NULL)"


"INSERT INTO dbo.Locations VALUES ('', '', '', '', , , SYSDATETIME(), NULL)"


"INSERT INTO dbo.Locations VALUES ('', '', '', 'd6cf5587-46da-4484-9795-beb0a192cf18', , , SYSDATETIME(), NULL)"


"INSERT INTO dbo.Locations VALUES ('', '', '', '', , , SYSDATETIME(), NULL)"


#REF!


"INSERT INTO dbo.Locations VALUES ('', '', '', '', , , SYSDATETIME(), NULL)"


"INSERT INTO dbo.Locations VALUES ('', '', '', '', , , SYSDATETIME(), NULL)"


"INSERT INTO dbo.Locations VALUES ('', '', '', 'd6cf5587-46da-4484-9795-beb0a192cf18', , , SYSDATETIME(), NULL)"


"INSERT INTO dbo.Locations VALUES ('', '', '', '', , , SYSDATETIME(), NULL)"


"INSERT INTO dbo.Locations VALUES ('', '', '', '1,2', , , SYSDATETIME(), NULL)"


"INSERT INTO dbo.Locations VALUES ('', '', '', '', , , SYSDATETIME(), NULL)"


"INSERT INTO dbo.Locations VALUES ('', '', '', '2', , , SYSDATETIME(), NULL)"



For example the first one should pull through as "INSERT INTO dbo.Locations  VALUES ('L-1', 'ROLLER TRACK 1', 'Production', 'd6cf5587-46da-4484-9795-beb0a192cf18', 1, 1, SYSDATETIME(), NULL)"

.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues  Not sure i understand, but is it paste special values you need

Try this out:
Sub Test()
    Dim c As Range, wsSrc As Worksheet, rng As Range, cDest As Range
    
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LOCATIONS")
    Set rng = wsSrc.Range("A1:R" & wsSrc.Cells(wsSrc.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    'first destination cell
    Set cDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SQL").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).offset(1)
    
    For Each c In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas) 'only formulas...
        If InStr(1, c.Value, "dbo.Locations", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            cDest.Value = c.Value       'copy value
            Set cDest = cDest.offset(1) 'next destination cell
        End If
    Next c
End Sub

